# Probability of drawing a Nothing from a poker hand

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

I'm trying to figure out the probability of drawing a poker hand of no value from a deck of 53 cards (1 additional joker) the context that it cant contain a joker, and none of the cards can be the same number and or face, so this excludes straights flushes and suit patterns.

I think it is simply

$$\frac{^{13}C_5 \times \left(^4C_1\right)^5}{^{53}C_5}$$

Although I am most likely mistaken

Comment: This is from a 5 Card Hand

Comment: Did you exclude flushs?

Comment: What do you mean by "none of the cards can be the same"? Exact same card, same colour, same suit?

Comment: Just not the same number or face

Comment: How do you mean "this exclude suit patterns"? If you only care whether the cards have the same rank (I assume that's what you mean by "number or face"), then they can be of any suits (including a flush)?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\left(\binom{13}{5}-10\right)\times(4^5-4)}{\binom{53}{5}}$$
The $-10$ excludes straights, the $-4$ excludes flushes.